# Variable parameter in the definition of array

Tags: c#

I have the following code, which creates a 2D array in a nested loop, What I want to do is to create this 2D array each iteration but with name concatenated to "j" value . For example, 
In first iteration the result will be : `double[,] visualmatrix1`. 
I tried to put `+`j but it fails.

```
ExtractDescriptorsForm ex = new ExtractDescriptorsForm(65,10);
int a = ex.m_maxExtract;
for (int i = 0; i < m_descriptor.visualword.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
        double[,] visualmatrix = new double[m_descriptor.visualword.Length, 2];
        visualmatrix[i, 0] = m_descriptor.visualword[i].identifier;
        visualmatrix[i, 1] = (m_descriptor.visualword[i].tf) * (m_descriptor.visualword[i].idf);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't do this, but you can use array of `double[,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code lost the new-created array inside the loops, you should use a list to store the 2D arrays.

```
List<double[,]> arrays = new List<double[,]>();
ExtractDescriptorsForm ex = new ExtractDescriptorsForm(65,10);
int a = ex.m_maxExtract;
for (int i = 0; i < m_descriptor.visualword.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
        double[,] visualmatrix = new double[m_descriptor.visualword.Length, 2];
        visualmatrix[i, 0] = m_descriptor.visualword[i].identifier;
        visualmatrix[i, 1] = (m_descriptor.visualword[i].tf) * (m_descriptor.visualword[i].idf);
        arrays.Add(visualmatrix);
    }
}
```

Then access it by

```
arrays[n]
```

Comment: I can't .. I want the dimension of it length by 2 .. by this way I am changing the dimension

Comment: @user5507512 By the way, you can accept a answer by clicking the check mark logo on the left side of the answer.